# Blender hair systems

Tags: particles, hair

I'm new to Blender and want to use its hair systems. Despite watching numerous tutorials and researching online, I can't seem to find stable settings. My hair simulations either end up too jittery or clump together. I'm using Blender 3.6. Is there a node-based hair system with more stable hair dynamics available?
[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: thanks for nothings